# ¿Se pueden sumar dos campos de diferentes modelos en django?

Tags: python, django, sql, django-models

Tengo 3 modelos distintos y quiero sumar sus campos IntergerField para crear un total de ganancias pero no se si es posible, soy nuevo en esto.

esta es mi vista:

```py
def income(request):
context={}

if request.method == 'POST':
        date =  (request.POST.get('id_date'))
        context['canceled_service'] = CanceledService.objects.filter(canceled_by_client=False, cancellation_date = date).aggregate(Sum('service_canceled__price'))
        context['canceled_client'] = CanceledService.objects.filter(canceled_by_client=True, cancellation_date = date).aggregate(Sum('service_canceled__price'))
        context['comision'] = Service.objects.filter(payment_status=False, date_service = date).aggregate(Sum('services__income'))
        context['payments'] = Payments.objects.filter(date = date).aggregate(Sum('deposited_income'))

return render(request,'prueba2.html',context)
```

y quisiera sumar los datos que devuelven los primero 3 context para hacer un total. No he encontrado nada que me pueda ayudar por eso quiero ver si es posible hacer algo asi

Comment: Valeria, agrega el codigo que hayas intentado, para que te ayuden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer cualquier operación con campos de los modelos, siempre y cuando sea compatible, si lo que deseas es hacer una suma de un campo numérico puedes usar la función `sum()` de Python,

Ejemplo:

```
suma_total = sum([model1.precio, model2.tarifa, model3.gasto])
```

Answer (score 0):

No te sirve almacenar en variables en lugar del context y luego sumar esas variables?
Si igual los necesitas en el context lo puedes hacer desde las variables.